# Что влияет на правильную работу запроса в браузере?

Tags: javascript, get, браузер, webbrowser, response

На html-странице есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую посылаются определенные запросы.
Но за первым компьютером один из запросов перенаправляет на другой url (рисунок 1), а за вторым компьютером не отрабатывается (рисунок 2).
Что может быть причиной такого поведения?

Рисунок 1:
[image: Рисунок 1]

Рисунок 2:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Урлы разные. А если на первой машине перейти на тот же url, что был на второй, то каков результат?

Comment: @Дмытрык, к трем компьютерам подключили три одинаковых телефона с одинаковыми прошивками. Соответственно, каждый телефон на своем компьютере получил ip-адрес, на который отправляется указанный в верхнем посте запрос.
Проблема в том, что на двух компьютерах при выполнении данного запроса происходит редирект на другой URL, а на третьей машине запрос не отрабатывает. 
Менял телефоны на компьютерах, все равно на одной определенной машине запрос не отрабатывает, на остальных все нормально, независимо от телефона.

Comment: параметр `random` в запросах разный

Comment: @Дмытрык, данный параметр при каждой попытке запроса разный.
Он точно не влияет на мою проблему.
На "правильных" машинах я могу отправить несколько раз этот запрос, будут различные значения данного параметра, и запрос будет выполняться правильно.
Может быть, есть какая - то настройка браузере, либо настройка сети, которая блокирует выполнение данного запроса?
P.S. прокси на всех трех компьютерах отключены.